# Spring scheduler in multiple server nodes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-scheduled

I am using the Spring scheduler using cron to run my task every 5 minutes.Now we have implemented a load balancer with seven websphere nodes. And since there is some delay while publishing my application to all the seven nodes,the scheduler job is not running at the same time in all the nodes.How can we make sure that all the nodes run the scheduled job at the same time(All the nodes are having the same system time)

Comment: This is one of the questions I ask first when people tell me they want to make a scheduled job.. To the problem at hand... Why do the jobs need to execute at the same time?

Comment: Its a sort of cache refresh.So I need to have consistent data across all the nodes since the requests can hit any node.

Comment: OK, I'd venture to say that the problem is then rather cache invalidation than scheduling. But let's assume you can't fix cache invalidation then you still have the problem that you will never be able to make the scheduler run at the same time across all the nodes. You will have to select an error margin that you are happy with or use a product like Couchbase or Redis and centralise your cache

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662275/scheduled-tasks-with-multiple-servers-single-point-of-responsibility